# I was caught cheating in a University exam. No action was taken but my professor is very angry with me. My main concern is how to face my classmates

Tags: university, exams, cheating

I was caught cheating in a University exam. However, no action was taken because I am a good student. Moreover, my professor is very angry with me.

My main concern now is how to face my classmates and friends in the remaining papers.

I think that people have lost all respect for me and think badly of me. How should I handle this situation now?

Comment: Can you explain how your post is different from "I got caught doing a bad thing, how can I avoid any consequences of my own actions?"

Comment: Regrets are important, they help you to do better in future.  Acknowledge your mistake, make amends as best you can (see @Buffy's answer), make sure you don't do it again and carry on.  Don't ignore your regrets, but don't be crushed by them either - that is unhelpful.  In Japan they have a thing called Kintsugi - repairing ceramics with gold cement, which becomes part of the aesthetic of the piece.  It seems to me to be a good metaphor for life - our flaws are part of what define us, properly repaired they can be a good thing.

Comment: "Though no action was taken because I am a good student." I'd say that is a *really* bad reason for not taking action, I think your professor needs some gold cement as well ;o)

Comment: What does "good student" mean? Are your grades good? Have they been achieved the same way as this case now, in which you were merely caught or are you really a normally good student who panicked this one time? Don't answer this here, just reflect on it. The situation is very different if it is a one-off or this is just the first time you got caught.

Comment: If no action was taken, do your classmates and friends actually know you cheated? Are you ashamed that now they know you cheated, or are you ashamed intrinsically of your own actions and getting caught didn’t actually factor into it?

Answer (score 7):

If you do something bad, then you need to accept the consequences. You may need, in some cases, to take effective action to ameliorate any negative outcomes of your action. If you have behaved badly in public, or it becomes public, one place to start is with a sincere apology, not a "no-pology", to those witnesses.

"I'm sorry that you were offended" isn't an apology. "I'm sorry that I did the bad thing and will work to improve" is an apology. Make sure you know the difference. The first is a kind of arrogance. Maybe people will choose to give you another chance. Maybe they will require some action on your part.

In a different context I've been in a similar situation. It worked out for me, but not without embarrassment, and not without changing some behavior.

---

Note also, that everyone has failings at times. No-one is perfect in every way at all times.

Comment: A missing part of your apology is acknowledging the harm caused to others.

Comment: @BryanKrause, subsumed into "the bad thing", actually. But yes. Make it obvious that you understand the harm caused.

Comment: I will adopt the word nopology. Genius.

Answer (score 2):

[Sir Gawain and the Green Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Gawain_and_the_Green_Knight) is a
late 14th-century chivalric romance in Middle English alliterative verse.

The summary on the wikipedia page ends with

> Gawain is ashamed to have behaved deceitfully, but the Green Knight laughs and pronounces him the most blameless knight in all the land. The two part on cordial terms. Gawain returns to Camelot wearing the sash as a token of his failure to keep his promise. The Knights of the Round Table absolve him of the blame and decide that henceforth each will wear a green sash in recognition of Gawain's adventure and as a reminder to be honest.

Comment: Are you suggesting OP wear a Green Sash?